# Recover files from corrupt archive

Tags: linux, tar

I have a tar file of 40Gb but when I open it with the archive manager on Ubuntu I get only 512MB. The major part of my files are messing. Even when I do:

```
tar -tf myfile.tar.gz
```

I don't get the list of all my files. When I create the file I used the command:

```
tar -zcvf myfile.tar.gz myhomefolder
```

And then I stopped the command as I don't want to compress (it takes too long) and run:

```
tar cvf myfile.tar.gz myhomefolder
```

On Windows when I use 7-Zip I get this error:

```
There are data after the end of file
```

The problem is that there's a bad end in the file. How to do to remove that end. What are the software that can make open the file in binary mode or something like this.

How can I get my files?

Answer (score 2):

You could try the utility [gzrecover](https://github.com/arenn/gzrt) and then extract the recovered archive with [cpio](https://www.gnu.org/software/cpio/manual/cpio.html).

It has assisted with recovering corrupted archives in the past, but your mileage may vary. I'm having an issue where it can't recover an archive for me, so fair warning.

---

EDIT: By a mod threatening me violently with a knife, I'll add some details how I recovered archives beforehand. (I'm kidding. Don't hurt me, @Scott!)

You can install both packages by using

```
sudo apt-get install cpio gzrt
```

After you've ensured both packages are installed, lets get to work.

First, put your archive where you don't mind the data being extracted. From there, you can run

```
gzrecover broken-archive.tar.gz
```

gzrecover will likely take some time, depending on how large the archive is. However, with any luck, you'll see "broken-archive.tar.recovered" in the same directory after the operation has completed.

The recovered archive has likely sustained some kind of damage as well; this is where cpio comes in handy. It should already be installed on your system.

To extract the recovered archive, use

```
cpio -F broken-archive.tar.recovered -i -v
```

**Be aware that cpio will spew out an extensively large amount of information during this time. I recommend you do this on a separate tty entirely instead of a terminal on your X session.** To do this, you can just press CTRL+ALT+F1 and your screen will switch to a terminal. To return to your X session, press CTRL+ALT+F8 (may vary, but usually is F7-9).

The process of extracting the recovered archive is also going to be rather intensive. As cpio is not optimized for use with multiple cores, it will stick to one core. Whatever core it happens to stick on, it will probably pin the core at 100% usage. If you have a dual-core machine, you might have to not use your computer for a while.

**Be forewarned that this process could actually take several days especially considering the size of the archive. Either find a different machine to offload this work onto (slower CPU's will make this take longer), plan to not use your computer for a while, or just brace for your system choking during work.** In addition, if you do run this within a terminal on your X session, you'll likely pin a second core to 100%. If you're an advanced user, you can use the `taskset` command to assign the process(es) to a specific core. However, that is outside of the scope of my answer.

I wish you the best of luck.

Comment: We’re looking for substantial answers that provide more detail.  Generally, an answer should explain how to solve the problem rather than just mentioning tools; please explain why you’re recommending them as a solution, and see [How do I recommend software in my answers?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5329/150988)

Comment: @Scott The gzrecover page contains more than sufficient documentation on how to use these tools. I don't feel like I need to be a proxy for information. In fact, it is literally on his site on how the author of the software recovered corrupted gzip archives.

I recommended them based on personal experience, which was also stated in my answer. I reviewed the question and I can't find any content that my answer doesn't have to assume. The software is simple enough for this purpose.

Comment: Super User’s purpose is to build a knowledge base rather than a collection of links to answers elsewhere.  Google often sends people here; we want them to find useful information *on* our site.  Besides, external links can break, in which case your answer would have little value.

Comment: @Scott Alright, alright. I changed the contents of the answer .. but then realized that the question is a year old. Oh well, maybe that Google theory will help out some poor soul.

Answer (score 0):

First `tar cvf myfile.tar.gz myhomefolder` should be `tar cvf myfile.tar myhomefolder`.

Second you could try `tar xvf myfile.tar.gz`.