# gzip archive with damaged begin

Tags: linux, archiving, gzip

How to recover as much as possible gzip file content when begin of this file is damaged?

Is it possible? I tried commands gunzip -c , zcat, openssl zlib -d   etc.
Unfortunately that commands doesn't work.

For reproduce this problem try pack into *.gz anything, I suggest text data (it can be HTML, XML, JSON or similar text based format). But compressed file should be at least 20kb size. next try:

```
tail -c 1000 filename.txt.gz|gzip -d
```

It will fail. any suggestions?

Comment: With the beginning of the file missing, you might out of luck. Did you read this: http://www.gzip.org/recover.txt?

Comment: of course I read this. but there is only common explanation. I hope it is possible find compression dictionary reset and start decompressing from this position. but I completly don't know how to do it. At now I see, gzip can't do it.

Comment: @Znik I answered a question that might help you here. I cannot promise anything considering this archive sounds like it is in bad shape. [Here you go.](https://superuser.com/questions/751775/recover-files-from-corrupt-archive/1021058#1021058) Good luck.